# Domain Name cannot be changed in Apache on CentOS 7

Tags: apache, url, dns

I have set up a server with a wiki and Wordpress and Nextcloud on a new Domain, let's say it's testing.com. When I was finished, I wanted to change the Domain from testing.com to realdomain.com.

The server is running CentOS 7 with httpd (apache), so I changed the ServerName in /etc/httpd/conf/ to "realdomain.com". Then I changed the VirtualHosts in all the files in /etc/httpd/conf.d.

I added the new Domain to the trusted Domains of the Wordpress, Nextcloud and wiki. I restarted the httpd service and the server itself.
Yet, when I open realdomain.com in browser, it shows me my websites, but it puts testing.com in the address field.

I tried using mod_rewrite to change the URL, but then my webbrowser tells me that the site doesnt redirect correctly and that the redirects never stop.
I tried those rewrite rules in the .conf files and in the .htaccess (not simultaneously)- no success.

I removed all my files in conf.d and created a new DocumentRoot with a simple helloWorld.html - The Url still gets rewritten to testing.com.

Are there any other locations that could have rewrite rules? Did I miss anything?

Thank you so much in advance, this is killing me!